# Bind loop index with function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I correctly bind the value `j` in the example below?

```
for (j = 0; j < shorts[i+1].length; j++) {
    $('#Container').append($('<button id="but'+(j+1)+'" type="button" onclick="func(this,j)">'+ values[j]+'</button>'));
)};
```

Comment: What's the problem? `j` is concatenated to a string.

Comment: Yuck with using inline events to bind the elements. There is no need to do it that way. What is `j` being used for? There is probably a better solution.

Comment: @epascarello I need to look a translation in an array using the index of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` should be concatenated as a variable otherwise it would be considered as a string and the onclick method would look like this `func(this,j)`.

This should do it `onclick="func(this,'+j+')"`

```
for (j = 0; j < shorts[i+1].length; j++) {
    $('#Container').append($('<button id="but'+(j+1)+'" type="button" onclick="func(this,'+j+')">'+ values[j]+'</button>'));
};
```

---

### Option 2

You can also do it by binding like this instead of inline onclick method

```
var $button = $('<button />')
  .attr('id', j+1)
  .text(j+1)
  .on('click', func.bind(null, j+1));
  $('#Container').append($button);
```

This way the value j+1 will be available to the function.

```js
function func(a){
  alert(a);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  var $button = $('<button />')
  .attr('id', j+1)
  .text(j+1)
  .on('click', func.bind(null, j+1));
  $('body').append($button);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `j` out of String and concatenate it properly

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teL9jzee/)

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 3];

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var div = $('<button id="but' + (j + 1) + '" type="button" onclick="func(this,' + j + ')">' + values[j] + '</button>');
    $('#mydiv').append(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either by using basic string concats, like so:

```
$('#Container').append($('<button id="but'+(j+1)+'" type="button" onclick="func(this,'+j+')">'+ values[j]+'</button>'));
```

Or you can use the properties of the event object to pull information from the element that is being clicked. See the section on `srcElement` [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/events-and-javascript-part-3-the-event-object.html).

That would be done by defining a function like

```
function(event){
//pull info from event with
event.srcElement
//use that to decide what to do inside the function
}
```

and passing that string into your html `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

Append the buttons without the inline click handlers.

Add a delegated click handler, and you can access the button's position using the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```js
var values= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  $('#Container').append($('<button>' + values[j] + '</button>'));
}

$('#Container').on('click', 'button', function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container"></div>
```